# img tag not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css

My problem is this: https://jsfiddle.net/a4uxteqc/3/

```
<style>
a.button {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#btnTwitch {
    background-color: #6441a5;
}

#btnYoutube {
    background-color: #b2071d;
}

#btnInsta {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 90%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
}

#btnTwitter {
    background-color: #26a7de;
}

#btnFacebook {
    background-color: #39569c;
}

#btnDiscord {
    background-color: #7289DA;
    align-content: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/83f84e31ea.js"></script>
<body>    
        <a class="button fa fa-twitch" id="btnTwitch" href="https://www.twitch.tv/kirbbytv"></a>
        <a class="button fa fa-youtube-play" id="btnYoutube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPDHhUwsQHnmwyfDU87M4zw"></a>
        <a class="button fa fa-instagram" id="btnInsta" href="https://www.instagram.com/kirbbytv/"></a>
        <a class="button fa fa-twitter" id="btnTwitter" href="https://twitter.com/kirbbyTV"></a>
        <a class="button fa fa-facebook-square" id="btnFacebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/kirbbytv"></a>
        <img id="btnDiscord" src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/108-1083707_logo-discord-png-download-red-discord-logo-transparent.png" alt="Discord Logo" onclick="openDiscord()">    
</body>
```

First I tried to contain the `<img>` with a `<a>`, but that made the background rectangle 70x76 while the FontAwesome rectangles were 70x70.
Now the `<img>` is positioned higher than all the `<a>` and I can't find the reason for it.

Can anyone tell me how I get the last "button" to the same position and size as the first 5 or how I can do it with an enclosing `<a>` and make that the same size as the other 5 "buttons"

Comment: Why are you not keeping everything consistent and use the discord icon from fontawesome?

For your information, they do have it: https://fontawesome.com/icons/discord

Comment: not in the free version though or am I missing something?

Comment: use `flex` for centering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an updated version of Font Awesome and have it all consistent. For example, the v5.14.

You will need to check the width of the icon containers though. But it looks better with the Font Awesome Discord icon.

```css
  body {
        background-color: grey;
    }
    
svg.button {
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    
    #discordLogo {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    
    #btnTwitch {
        background-color: #6441a5;
    }
    
    #btnYoutube {
        background-color: #b2071d;
    }
    
    #btnInsta {
        background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 90%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
    }
    
    #btnTwitter {
        background-color: #26a7de;
    }
    
    #btnFacebook {
        background-color: #39569c;
    }
    
        #btnDiscord {
        background-color: #7289DA;
        align-content: center;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/js/all.js"></script>
<body>    
        <a class="button fab fa-twitch" id="btnTwitch" href="https://www.twitch.tv/kirbbytv"></a>
        <a class="button fab fa-youtube" id="btnYoutube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPDHhUwsQHnmwyfDU87M4zw"></a>
        <a class="button fab fa-instagram" id="btnInsta" href="https://www.instagram.com/kirbbytv/"></a>
        <a class="button fab fa-twitter" id="btnTwitter" href="https://twitter.com/kirbbyTV"></a>
        <a class="button fab fa-facebook-square" id="btnFacebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/kirbbytv"></a>
        <a class="button fab fa-discord" id="btnDiscord" href="https://www.facebook.com/kirbbytv"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: In FontAwesome v4 the discord logo is not existent, I didn't see you could also use v5 of Font Awesome for free. I created a free kit of FontAwesome v5 and that works fine with the discord logo, thank you. PS: The discord logo used in the demo above was just a random logo from google i found and was only for demonstration. In my version I used a png of the discord icon that looked the same as the FontAwesome logos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use flex

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.flexme {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* remove or change this if you dont want */
  align-items: center
}

a.button {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#discordLogo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#btnTwitch {
  background-color: #6441a5;
}

#btnYoutube {
  background-color: #b2071d;
}

#btnInsta {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 90%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
}

#btnTwitter {
  background-color: #26a7de;
}

#btnFacebook {
  background-color: #39569c;
}

#btnDiscord {
  background-color: #7289DA;
  align-content: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/83f84e31ea.js"></script>
<div class="flexme">
  <a class="button fa fa-twitch" id="btnTwitch" href="https://www.twitch.tv/kirbbytv"></a>
  <a class="button fa fa-youtube-play" id="btnYoutube" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPDHhUwsQHnmwyfDU87M4zw"></a>
  <a class="button fa fa-instagram" id="btnInsta" href="https://www.instagram.com/kirbbytv/"></a>
  <a class="button fa fa-twitter" id="btnTwitter" href="https://twitter.com/kirbbyTV"></a>
  <a class="button fa fa-facebook-square" id="btnFacebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/kirbbytv"></a>
  <img id="btnDiscord" src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/108-1083707_logo-discord-png-download-red-discord-logo-transparent.png" alt="Discord Logo" onclick="openDiscord()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `parentDiv` to declare `flex` and `center` vertical with. `align-items: center`

```
.parentDiv {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Here is the [example on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0bin/adf2m7r3/4/)